# Iterate over two files Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have two CSV files and one is a list of airports and the second is a regions file that translates the region code of an airport to a region name. But the airport also has a municipality already given so I want to check for when the municipality is the same as the region.
I've come up with this but it is very slow, I can't use zip of course because it's not linear.
Each airport finds it's region code in the region file then compares the region name to muncipality.

```py
import csv
with open('airports.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as airport_csv:
        airport_csv_reader = csv.DictReader(filter(lambda row: row[0]!='#', airport_csv))
        for airport in airport_csv_reader:
            with open('regions.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as regions_csv:
                regions_csv = csv.DictReader(filter(lambda row: row[0]!='#', regions_csv))
                for region in regions_csv:
                    if region['code'] == airport['iso_region']:
                        if region['name'] == airport['municipality']:
                            print('ident', airport['ident'], 'municipality', airport['municipality'], 'region', region['name'])
```

Comment: We don't have any idea about your file size, but the reason that it is slow is because you are checking everything against everything. (`for airport in ...` and `for region in ...`). This scales with the size of `airport.csv` and `regions.csv`. Simplest solution, use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html#getting-started), load the csv's using [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) and use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) to combine the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just do something like:

```
import csv

with open('regions.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:                
  regions_csv_reader = csv.DictReader(filter(lambda row: row[0]!='#', f))
  seen = [(row['code'], row['name']) for row in regions_csv_reader]

with open('airports.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  airport_csv_reader = csv.DictReader(filter(lambda row: row[0]!='#', f))
    for row in airport_csv_reader:        
      if (row['iso_region'], row['municipality']) in seen:
        print('ident', row['ident'], 'municipality', row['municipality'], 'region', row['municipality'])
```

However I do not see the point of printing twice the region name/municipality as you where looking at rows where the airport municipality is equal to the region name.

Comment: Works perfectly, yeah I realized that I don't need to print it twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for this being so slow is the repetive opening of files, consider loading the "regions.csv" file before starting your for-loop:

```
regions_csvFile = open('regions.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
regions_csv = csv.DictReader(filter(lambda row: row[0]!='#', regions_csv))
regions_csvFile.close()
```

and then the rest of your code

Comment: I tried this actually my self I think it doesn't work because the DictReader only loads in a single line at a time, so that way then it leaves the loop with only one region. However, the solution below this works as it loads each row into a list that is kept.

Comment: Ah sweet! Didn't know it worked like that, happy you found a solution.